# Please describe why the examiner chose to allow this application in light of the prior art of record

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US6932368](https://www.google.com/patents/US6932368)

Comment: Please demonstrate how a specific piece of prior art applies to the claims of the patent.

Comment: please check reference citations

Comment: The reference citations were already compared against the patent claims and found to differ in scope. See the prosecution history in Public Pair.

Comment: See https://register.epo.org/ipApplication?documentId=4-3-US%20%201081644605P1%20&number=US.81644604.A

Specifically, paragraph 2 describes the reasons for allowance: "The prior art shows a number of bicycle sail configurations, but none include all of the details claimed, including ..."